# Typical range of a small hole gauge.

Tags: measurements

I want to get this out there. What is a typical and common  range of a small hole gauge?

Comment: Are you trying to measure the diameters of small holes? Please be more specific.

Comment: Please be more specific. ID or OD measurement? At any rate, precision gage pins exist for nearly all practical diameters. Typically appx .004" diameter and greater in increments of .0001". There are specialty tolerances and sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Small hole gauges usually come in sets and their range will typically vary between 0.125" to 0.500".

This is according to NTMA Catelog Number 5023 measuring and gauging in the maching shop chapter 4.